# How to have a decorator return a (cached) property iff it was previously None?

Tags: python, caching, decorator, nonetype

In a class where an argument is optional and calculated else, I typically have something like

```
class Demo(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        if self._value is None:
            # some calculations to get value
            self._value = value
        return self._value
```

which is quite noisy IMHO and similar to a memoization preface. I'd prefer something like

```
    @property_if_None
    def value(self):
        # some calculations to get value
        return value
```

Were `value` not optional but simply not set I'd use `@functools.lru_cached`, but that cannot work.

---

Of course I could simply change `__init__` to

```
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        if value is None:
            # some calculations to get value
        self.value = value
```

but let's assume `# some calculations to get value` is lengthy and should be in its own function - which I'd prefer to call `value()` thereby effectively making `value` a `@property`, but if and only if it was not set to a value ≠ `None`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly not the most perfect solution, but here's my go:

```
import functools

# http://stackoverflow.com/a/28961925/321973
def property_if_None_generator(f, cached=False):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(self):
        value = self.__getattribute__('_' + f.__name__)
        if value is not None:
            return value
        else:
            return f(self)
    if cached:
        wrapped = functools.lru_cache()(wrapped)
    return property(wrapped)

property_if_None = lambda f: property_if_None_generator(f, cached=False)
cached_property_if_None = lambda f: property_if_None_generator(f, cached=True)
```

then the question's example would turn into

```
class Demo(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self._value = value

    @chached_property_if_None
    def value(self):
        # some calculations to get value
        return value
```

Comment: I believe in your Demo class, it would need to set and return `self._value` to actually work.

Comment: @martineau Can you be more specific about that? It is set to an optional constructor argument (or `None` if not provided), but it certainly doesn't need to be returned - the `@cached_property_if_None` decorator is a `@property_if_None` wrapped by `@functools.lru_cache()` which takes the returned `value` and caches it.

Comment: Awesome. A downvote without comment. Now _that_ helps me improving... Any _actual_ feedback would be appreciated, I posted this code on [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/84188/31087) as well..